# Why is this array changing when I'm not operating on it?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have two arrays:

```
order = np.array([ 0, 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, 10,  7,  8,  9])
X = np.array([[1,1], [1,2], [2,1], [1,7], [7,3], [8,3], [8,2], [10,5], [10,6], [10,7], [10,1]]
```

And I'm running the foll)owing code:

```
m,n = X.shape
for i in range(m):
     print( i," ",X[order[i]])
```

I get the following result:

```
0   [1 1]
1   [1 2]
2   [2 1]
3   [1 7]
4   [7 3]
5   [8 3]
6   [8 2]
7   [10  1]
8   [10  1]
9   [10  1]
10  [10  1]
```

Why are the last elements changed? I don't see why X is changed by indexing some elements.

edit: added np.array

Comment: Your code does not produce the output you are saying it does - `'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your output. I used your loop and `X[order])` (assuming both objects as numpy arrays) but got the same output twice (different than yours). Maybe you modified `order` somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write np.array.

I'm printing order right before the code and it is the same as in the post. 
I'm not doing anything else than what I wrote in the post, so I really don't know why it's not reproducable. Maybe there's something else that's wrong with my python

Comment: Your code as provided gives different results than your supposed output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import numpy
# your data (order and X)
m, n = numpy.shape(X)
for i in range(m):
    print(i, " ", X[order[i]])
```

Output:

```py
0   [1, 1]
1   [1, 2]
2   [2, 1]
3   [1, 7]
4   [7, 3]
5   [8, 3]
6   [8, 2]
7   [10, 1]
8   [10, 5]
9   [10, 6]
10   [10, 7]
```